# CSS popups on menu items in Semantic UI 2.2

Tags: css, menu, popup, semantic-ui

Using Semantic UI 2.2.9 I am trying to put a vertical icon menu down the left hand side of the page, and have popups appear to the right of each menu item on hover. I am using the CSS popups in Semantic UI 2.2.

The body of the popup itself appears correctly but there is a rendering glitch where a diagonal white line appears over the menu. I think this may be the arrow of the popup, because that isn't showing up, but adding `data-variation="basic"` didn't make it go away.

If I put an actual button in the menu then its tooltip works fine, but buttons don't style all that well in Semantic UI's menu collection.

Here's a small JS Fiddle showing the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/richardviney/g8cxnqaf/3/

Any ideas?

I also just noticed that the popups don't appear at all in Safari 10. Don't know why, but it might be relevant. They do appear in Chrome 56.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that making the element a .item is the cause. Basically, css tooltips rely extensively on :before & :after, and will be broken by anything else that uses that, such as the menu/item pair. Annoying, but we probably should expect css pseudo-classes to solve everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases like this you need to avoid Semantic UI's CSS popups and use the JavaScript popups instead. The CSS popups are handy, but they have limitations of which this appears to be one. Enable a JavaScript popup on an element by running this code:

```
$('#my-element').popup({
  content: 'Popup content'
})
```

Semantic UI's complete documentation for using popups is here:

https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/usage.